# Jenkins email-ext plugin "ghost" configuration issue

Tags: jenkins, hudson

We have an old install of Hudson (ver. 1.379, yes that old...) that hasn't been upgraded yet (and I am not quite sure when and if it will be by the people responsible for it).

There seems to be some place, apparently unaccessible from the web interface, were additional recipients for the email-ext plugin were added...

Problem is, those recipients no longer exist and quite a few people (mostly unrelated to the people who use Hudson) get spammed by bounces from those emails...

For email-ext I get this in the plugin page:

version: 2.12 installed: 2.8

I have looked at the configs and I believe email-ext config should be under "Editable Email Notification" of that job...

I see some of the recipients of those emails but not the person who left, it looks like this was configured elsewhere, maybe manually in some sort of config file.

Where can I look for this?

Thank you!

Puzzled!

Comment: It was under the "Before Build" trigger in the "Extended Email Notifications". Thank you Slav!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is global configuration. Go to **Manage Hudson**, then **Configure System** (the wording my be different based on your version, but you should end up here `http://<hudsonurl>/configure`. You need to have global administrative permissions to access this, but based on what you are saying, it sound like you do not.

Based on your version of the plugin, under **Extended E-mail Notification**, you will see **Default Recipients**. Older versions of the plugin did not have that feature.

Also, under the job configuration itself, there are several places to override/add to the list of recipients, the most buried of which is under the **Triggers**

- Click **Advanced...** button under **Editable Email Notification**
- For each trigger, click **Expand** link.

Lastly, it is possible that people are included on the emails cause they were **Culprits**. In Hudson's terms, these are people who committed to SCM since the last successful build. If the build has been failing since then for a long time, they are just there as culprits. The only way to "reset" the culprits is to let the job build successfully

Comment: Hi! It was under the "Before Build" trigger in the "Extended Email Notifications".